# Использование ресурсов внутри jar в Maven

Tags: java, maven

jar работает только при наличии трёх папок рядом с ним. Тащить их за собой не очень хочется.
Первая папка - с картинками
Вторая папка - с конфиг-файлами, которые приложение читает и иногда изменяет
Третья папка - jar-зависимости Maven

Итоговый jar-файл запаковывается в exe, но и рядом с этим exe-файлом необходимо иметь эти три папки... Есть какой-то выход?

Добавляю информацию: с картинками разобрался, всё просто... А с конфиг-файлами как? Как перезаписывать файлы внутри jar? И с библиотеками всё еще непонятно...

Содержимое пома:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.launcher.Launcher</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                          ${project.build.directory}/lib
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Нужно для начала показать содержимое pom. А вообще похоже, что тебе нужен maven-assembly plugin

Comment: короче, основная цель, чтобы эти библиотеки собирал как-то

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно добавить плагин мавена [maven-assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html), по ссылке пример использования. Он как раз все зависимости, ресурсы, исходники и документацию собирает в один jar файл.

[Описание плагина](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)